# Duplicate ids when using TableGenerator

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

Upon attempting to save a new row in a table I am getting a duplicate id error and a failure to persist the data. It's in our stage environment so I don't currently have access to the logs, though I'm trying to get it temporarily in order to figure this out. I only have the underlying error message so far:

```
Duplicate entry '2219193' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

We use a sequence table and I am using TableGenerator annotated like so:

```
@Entity
@TableGenerator(name="AUDITTRAIL_GEN", table="sequence", pkColumnName = "sequence_name",
        valueColumnName = "sequence_value", pkColumnValue="seq_audittrailid", allocationSize=50)
public class FtpAuditTrail {
    ...
}
```

I don't have any special settings enabled for hibernate. Literally the only properties I am setting are username, password, driver, and repository URL.

There is another server (with a different application than mine) that periodically updates the same database and adds rows in the table.

I am using Java 1.6.0_65, MySQL 5.5.11 and the latest release of hibernate as of this writing, 4.2.2.Final.

Edited: I have confirmed with the owner of the other application that they update the sequence table to a new value and then use the new value as the id of their new row in the shared table. Doesn't TableGenerator assume the value in the table is available for use?

Comment: Have you checked if the entry '2219193' already exists in the database?

Comment: Are you using multiple persistent units? The TableGenerator is only supposed to work if there's only one

Comment: @JCalcines - yes, it is. the duplicate entry error is legit.

Comment: @Guillaume - no, just one.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason for not using MySQL's auto-increment columns?

Comment: @Guillaume - It tends to get messy when you try to combine auto-incrementing and replication. Many people consider allowing the db control over id generation to be poor practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other (and previously, very long established) applications creating entries in the shared tables are expecting the value saved in the sequence table to be the last value used. So I need a custom id generator to do the same. Unless hibernate has an id generator that does what I want. But the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10648572/187423) suggests that you have to extend TableGenerator in your own custom class to make this happen.