# JPA Generated Table Stategy and Multitenancy

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

When a sequence based on the Table strategy is created,

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE,
                generator = "REFERENCES_GENERATOR") 
@Column(name = "MY_REFERENCE")
protected long _myReference;

@TableGenerator(name = "REFERENCES_GENERATOR", 
                table = "TABLE_NAME", 
                pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME",           
                valueColumnName = "REFERENCE",
                pkColumnValue = PK_KEY,
                allocationSize = 1)
```

**But this way , the sequence is NOT created tenantized , so the sequence is being used across two diferent tenants.**

In Hibernate one trick would be to use [Generic Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311131/can-tablegenerator-save-the-last-used-id-in-the-table-instead-of-the-next-avail)  to inject someway the tenant id

Anyway to do this in **EclipseLink**?